# To what extent does Arata become weaker?

Tags: trinity-seven

I read on the wiki that he:

> gives up his demon element to Anastasia

As I haven't watched that far in the series yet, I'm curious to know the extent of his power loss and if he becomes much weaker from then on? Does he ever get his powers back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He gives up his Magic King Element in order to let Anastasia-L remain in their world, so he's not a Magic King Candidate anymore, but since he had been training in Magic for a while by then he can still use magic, since the Magic King Element was more of a mana tank, so he's considerably weaker but not powerless. In order to overcome this he goes with Ana and Arsha to the Akasha Academy and studies to become a Magic Swordsman since he still had Judecca and learns to harness it's power. After a 300 day training period it proves enough to overcome the loss of the MKE, and so far, it seems he's got even more powerful, at least enough to instill fear into the Astil Raddix (a grimoire powerful enough to fight both Levi and Akio at the same time without much trouble pre-timeskip).